# How do I use xslt to generate many table with one set of data?

Tags: xslt

I have the following XML

```
    <ArrayOfOperatorStation>
     <OperatorStation>
        <Name>OS1</Name>
        <OS>Microsoft Windows XP Professional</OS>
        <IP>172.20.254.90</IP>
        <Version>5.1.2600</Version>
        <Alive>true</Alive>
        <Files>
          <FileComparison>
            <Filename>C:\file1.txt</Filename>
            <Hash>82c7aa19c690bb41e91c6b71d22bb533</Hash>
          </FileComparison>
          <FileComparison>
            <Filename>C:\file3.txt</Filename>
            <Hash>82c7aa19c690bb41e91c6b71d22bb533</Hash>
          </FileComparison>
        </Files>
    </OperatorStation>
    <OperatorStation>
        <Name>OS2</Name>
        <OS>Microsoft Windows XP Professional</OS>
        <IP>172.20.254.91</IP>
        <Version>5.1.2600</Version>
        <Alive>true</Alive>
        <Files>
          <FileComparison>
            <Filename>C:\file1.txt</Filename>
            <Hash>82c7aa19c690bb41e91c6b71d22bb533</Hash>
          </FileComparison>
          <FileComparison>
            <Filename>C:\file2.txt</Filename>
            <Hash>82c7aa19c690bb41e91c6b71d22bb533</Hash>
          </FileComparison>
        </Files>
  </OperatorStation>
</ArrayOfOperatorStation>
```

and would like to generate to diffent tables of this data in the final html result.

```
Operator staion
----------------
OS1     |  OS2
Alive   |  Alive

and another one with a filelist
OS1    | OS2    | etc...
---------------------------
File1  | File1
File3  | File2
```

I have trouble making the second list, i have no idea how to begin. with the "query" at all.

Comment: You are using xlst-1.0 o2 2.0? And is the FileComparison in Files always the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are solution for your second table. Which also considers the possibility that the amount of files for OperatorStation could differ.

Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="kOperatorStationFiles" match="FileComparison"  use="../preceding-sibling::OperatorStation[1]/Name" />

    <xsl:template match="OperatorStation" mode="files">
        <xsl:param name="fileNr" />
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('kOperatorStationFiles', Name)[$fileNr]/Filename"/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="OperatorStation" mode="header">
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//OperatorStation" mode="header"/>
            </tr>
            <!-- find max files -->
            <xsl:for-each select="//OperatorStation" >
                <xsl:sort select="count(key('kOperatorStationFiles', Name))" order="descending" />
                <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('kOperatorStationFiles', Name)" >
                        <tr>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="//OperatorStation" mode="files">
                            <xsl:with-param name="fileNr" select="position()" />
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this (changed) input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ArrayOfOperatorStation>
    <OperatorStation>
        <Name>OS1</Name>
        <OS>Microsoft Windows XP Professional</OS>
        <IP>172.20.254.90</IP>
        <Version>5.1.2600</Version>
        <Alive>true</Alive>
    </OperatorStation>
    <Files>
        <FileComparison>
            <Filename>C:\file1.txt</Filename>
            <Hash>82c7aa19c690bb41e91c6b71d22bb533</Hash>
        </FileComparison>
        <FileComparison>
            <Filename>C:\file3.txt</Filename>
            <Hash>82c7aa19c690bb41e91c6b71d22bb533</Hash>
        </FileComparison>
    </Files>

    <OperatorStation>
        <Name>OS2</Name>
        <OS>Microsoft Windows XP Professional</OS>
        <IP>172.20.254.91</IP>
        <Version>5.1.2600</Version>
        <Alive>true</Alive>
    </OperatorStation>
    <Files>
        <FileComparison>
            <Filename>C:\file1.txt</Filename>
            <Hash>82c7aa19c690bb41e91c6b71d22bb533</Hash>
        </FileComparison>
        <FileComparison>
            <Filename>C:\file2.txt</Filename>
            <Hash>82c7aa19c690bb41e91c6b71d22bb533</Hash>
        </FileComparison>
        <FileComparison>
            <Filename>C:\file471.txt</Filename>
            <Hash>82c7aa19c690bb41e91c6b71d22bb533</Hash>
        </FileComparison>

    </Files>
</ArrayOfOperatorStation>
```

It generates the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>OS1</td>
    <td>OS2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C:\file1.txt</td>
    <td>C:\file1.txt</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C:\file3.txt</td>
    <td>C:\file2.txt</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td/>
    <td>C:\file471.txt</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Update:
Because of comment "*The files have to be included in the -parent.*"
Some small changes will do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="kOperatorStationFiles" match="FileComparison"  use="ancestor::OperatorStation/Name" />

    <xsl:template match="OperatorStation" mode="files">
        <xsl:param name="fileNr" />
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('kOperatorStationFiles', Name)[$fileNr]/Filename"/>
        </td>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="OperatorStation" mode="header">
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/OperatorStation" mode="header"/>

            </tr>
            <!-- find max files -->
            <xsl:for-each select="/*/OperatorStation" >
                <xsl:sort select="count(key('kOperatorStationFiles', Name))" order="descending" />
                <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('kOperatorStationFiles', Name)" >
                        <tr>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/OperatorStation" mode="files">
                            <xsl:with-param name="fileNr" select="position()" />
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>

                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Problem with this solution is that changing the input would break other parts of the code, that i cannot change. The files have to be included in the <operatorstation>-parent.

Comment: @schultz: Hm I can't follow you. Your example input is not well formed (wrong xml). There is at leased on superfluous  `</OperatorStation>`. But perhaps I did a wrong interpretation. Please correct your example.

Comment: Sorry about that. I did not spot that. I cut and pasted from a huge xml file into a smaller example.

Comment: @schultz: Did you have a look to the update. That should work with your updated question.

Comment: Thank you yes, that worked. This one i wouldnt have figured out on my own.